# export HTML input type "text" to a specific excel speadsheat starting on the next available line

Tags: excel

I have an HTML code that I would like to use to send text data to a specific excel spread sheet starting on the next available line and starting with column B. I have a code that opens a new excel spreadseet every time and sends data like it should. I want to modify the code to go to a specific spread sheet and keep adding additional data to the same sheet.
Here is the code that I have so far:

```
<script>
function ToExcel(){ 
if (window.ActiveXObject){ 
var xlApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
var xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(); 
var table=document.getElementById('inner_table')

//var tableCells=document.getElementById('inner_table').cells
var tableRows=document.getElementById('inner_table').rows
xlBook.worksheets("Sheet1").activate; 
var XlSheet = xlBook.activeSheet; 
xlApp.visible = true; 
var xlRow = 1;
var xlCol = 1;
var R=0;
while(tableRows[R] != null)
{
var tableCells =tableRows[R].cells
var C = 0; 
xlCol=1;
while(tableCells[C] != null)
{
XlSheet.cells(xlRow, xlCol).value = tableCells[C].childNodes[1].value;
xlCol++;
C++;
}
xlRow++;
R++;
} 
XlSheet.rows.autofit; 
XlSheet.columns.autofit; 
} 
} 
</script>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row number for the first empty row on the sheet (looking from the bottom of the sheet up) using something like:

```
var xlRow = XlSheet.cells(XlSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row+1 // -4162==xlUp
```